# PostgreSQL 9.0 HA load balancing between servers

Tags: postgresql, server-side-includes, load-balancing

Hey folks, I'm bashing my head to configure load balancing stuff between two database servers. I have no clue whether, I can find any mechanism to implement this. I already tried to implement Heart beat clustering but it requires virtual Ip wherein I can't create virtual IP or assign my own IP address in amazon EC2. Is there a way to configure PostgreSQL database servers in similar to Amazon load balancing kind of thing ? If so, please suggest the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For load balancing, what kind of load are you balancing?  Reads or writes? If you need to balance writes you'll need a multi-master replication solution.  Otherwise if it's mostly read only, there are plenty of master-slave solutions which allow you to write to the master then split up reads across multiple slaves.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [pgPool](http://www.pgpool.net/), works great.